# Boundedness of functions over a certain interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I was looking at my real analysis notebook from my undergrad days, and I stumbled upon the theorem that seems a bit counter intuitive to me. I was wondering if someone could explain or perhaps offer a proof. The theorem is as follows:

if $f$ is a real-valued function on $[0,1]$, then $f$ is bounded there,that is $\exists M, N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $M\leq f(x)\leq N$ for $\forall x\in [0,1]$.

Also, could someone explain why the theorem would not hold if the interval $(0,1)$ were used instead?

Comment: $f$ needs to be continuous for the Theorem. Consider $f(x)=1/x$ for the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: Are you saying boundedness $\implies$ continuity and vice versa? I was never taught that so I'm not sure

Comment: No. I meant your Theorem is false. A true theorem would be "If $f$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[0,1]$, then $f$ is bounded there.".

Comment: do you know already the Heine-Borel's theorem??

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the statement was "If $f$ is a **continuous** real-valued function on $[0,1]$, then $f$ is bounded there."

The proof of this uses compactness of $[0,1]$.

To whit: because $f$ is continuous, the pre-image of any open set is an open set.  We can cover all of $\mathbb{R}$ by the intervals $I_a:=(a-1,a+1)$, $a\in\mathbb{Z}$; let $P_a:=f^{-1}(I_a)$.

Then the sets $(P_a)_{a\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are an open cover of $[0,1]$, since the sets $I_a$ account for all of $\mathbb{R}$; so, by compactness of $[0,1]$, we can find $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $P_{a_1},P_{a_2},\ldots,P_{a_n}$ cover all of $[0,1]$.

But what does that mean?  That means that all of the possible output-values of $f$ lie in $I_{a_1},I_{a_2},\ldots,I_{a_n}$; in particular, we can take $N:=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}+1$ and $M:=\min\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}-1$, and we have $M\leq f(x)\leq N$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

The reason, then, that this result doesn't hold for $(0,1)$ is that we no longer have compactness.  To demonstrate that compactness is necessary, you can use the example that David Mitra gave in the comments: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A lovely discontinuous function unbounded on a closed interval is $f(p/q) = q$ on rationals and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part: Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact (so, closed and bounded by Heine-Borel) then the image $f[0,1]$ is also compact, hence bounded.